# Google Cloud Storage download fails in some users' devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'm creating an app with Unity3d 2019.2.9f1, and trying to utilize Google Cloud Storage as a data store of asset bundle.

In some users' environment, there were network errors below:

```
400 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/...
'Unable to complete SSL connection' response: 'Unable to complete SSL connection'
```

This error occurred in Samsung S7 edge、Redmi Note 7S, but wasn't seen in iPhone or many other android devices.

If anyone knows about this error, please help me...

Comment: This looks like is a known issue with SSL handler of unity

Some users reported this behavior

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-unable-to-complete-ssl-connection.566380

Answer (score 0):

I asked one user who was facing the error to go directly to the storage.googleapis.com link in his Google Chrome app, and it failed with "net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".
However, by shutting down and restarting device and uninstall&reinstalling the app from Google Play Store, he said the app started to work fine.... So anyway it seems it was solved